# Ruby - Parsing emails from text or html

Tags: ruby

From what I understand, Regex is not the best thing to use when scanning for emails within a given document. I am wondering if there are any alternatives to this? Or some best practice way that I'm unaware of?

Comment: What does a email in a document looks like?

Comment: Why not use a regex? People have been testing strings against regexes that define emails for a very long time.

Comment: Define what you mean by "emails". Email messages, with To:/From:/Subject: headers? Email addresses? Whichever it is, update your question and be more descriptive. Also, show examples of the text you'll be scanning, including target data you want to extract.

Answer (score 16):

For parsing jobs it is always a good idea to rely on libraries. You are right, a library will always have dealt with the problem in more detail than a regular expression, considering different cases, etc.

One Ruby library for parsing emails is [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail):

> Mail is an internet library for Ruby that is designed to handle emails
>   generation, **parsing** and sending in a simple, rubyesque manner.
>
> [...] Mail has been designed with a very simple object oriented
>   system that really opens up the email messages you are parsing, if you
>   know what you are doing, you can fiddle with every last bit of your
>   email directly.

Here is an example of how the email's content is accessed:

```
mail = Mail.read('/path/to/message.eml')

mail.envelope.from   #=> 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
mail.from.addresses  #=> ['mikel@test.lindsaar.net', 'ada@test.lindsaar.net']
mail.sender.address  #=> 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
mail.to              #=> 'bob@test.lindsaar.net'
mail.cc              #=> 'sam@test.lindsaar.net'
mail.subject         #=> "This is the subject"
mail.date.to_s       #=> '21 Nov 1997 09:55:06 -0600'
mail.message_id      #=> '<4D6AA7EB.6490534@xxx.xxx>'
mail.body.decoded    #=> 'This is the body of the email...
```

It also enables you to parse a multipart email, as well as test and extract the attachments.

Comment: I've only seen this type of example above everywhere and not something like `@my_subject_variable = mail.envelope.from`  Is it just a good copy and paste job, or is there a reason why everyone uses the same example?

Comment: @HerbMeehan The example is taken from the repository's README file. Certainly, you can use it in the way you have proposed.